# Reflection ValidateAttributes in partial model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reflection

I have Entity model:

```
public partial class CompanyTelephone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

And i create meta class for this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CompanyTelephoneMeta))]
public partial class CompanyTelephone
{
}

public class CompanyTelephoneMeta
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Телефон")]
    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Значение {0} должно содержать от {2} до 25 символов.")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

Why if i use GetProperties() in my Controller for CompanyTelephone class, he don't return validaton attributes?
[image: validationAttributes]

Comment: Sorry, i show wrong class. Now i edited this.

Comment: Are you sure your classes are in the same namespace ?